# How to query AWS DynamoDb using GSI Index and FilterExpression

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, typescript2.0

My DynamoDB database table is as follows. It has primary key(ID) and sort key (receivedTime).

```
  ID(primary key)   receivedTime(sort key)     Data
  ID1               1670739188                  3
  ID2               1670723198                  5
  ID2               1674785188                  7
  ID3               1670721388                  5
```

I want to query by ID and received time in range: - 
example : 
ID - ID2,
range -  1670723188 to 1673723188

I created GSI Index and Primary key is ID. I write query code like this,

```
 ID const params = {
    IndexName: 'Query-ID-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#ID = :ID',
    FilterExpression:
      '#receivedTime BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime ',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#ID': 'ID',
      '#receivedTime': 'receivedTime',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':ID': id,
      ':startTime': startTime,
      ':endTime': endTime,
    },
    TableName: 'tableName',
  };
  const data = await docClient.query(params).promise();
```

But data.Item is empty. Any one can help how to solve.

Comment: Why do you have GSI if the schema already matches your query? Why do you scan instead of query?

Comment: sorry for that i edit it now

Comment: No need to excuse yourself. Just use a regular query on your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need an index? Do the `Query` from your main table:

```
const params = {
    KeyConditionExpression: '#ID = :ID AND #receivedTime BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#ID': 'ID',
      '#receivedTime': 'receivedTime',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':ID': id,
      ':startTime': startTime,
      ':endTime': endTime,
    },
    TableName: 'tableName',
  };
  const data = await docClient.query(params).promise();
```